# Ошибка в изменении значения ключей в словаре Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

В словарь записывается кол-во встречающихся слов. Если слово не встречалось, то значение ключа изменяется на 0. Если же такое слово встречалось, то значения ключа увеличивается на 1. Написал вот это

```
for i in range(0, len(b)):
for j in range(0, len(b[i])):
    if b[i][j].lower() not in c:
        c[b[i][j]] = 0
    else:
        c[b[i][j]] += 1
```

Выдает ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То, что в словаре есть ключ `b[i][j].lower()`, совсем не означает, что в нём есть ключ `b[i][j]`. Ошибка возникает из-за того, что ключа `AbC` нет (при том, что ключ `abc` есть). Регистр важен!

Comment: А циклы у вас намерено так дивненько расположены? Или все-таки вторая строка должна быть с отступом?